# Combine elasticsearch js with bluebird

Tags: javascript, node.js, elasticsearch, bluebird

I am starting out with **node.js**, the **bluebird** promise framework. I am trying to integrate it with **elasticsearch** javascript driver. I managed to make it work using the following code. I would like to know if this is the best way to start the promise. I omitted the functions called in the *then* steps.

```
var esPromise = client.search({
    index: "myindex",
    searchType: "count",
    body: {
        aggs: {
            allIp: {
                terms: {
                    field: "ip",
                    size: 1000,
                    order: {
                        _term: "asc"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
});


new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    esPromise.then(resolve, reject);
})
    .then(extract_ips_from_aggs)
    .then(sort_ips)
    .then(log_ips)
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

Comment: the elasticsearch driver already uses bluebird internally, you can just `esPromise.then` no need for the promise constructor or all that.

Comment: Sometimes it is so easy to make something easy difficult. You are right, it works just like that.

Answer (score 1):

You can override the deferred object used internally like:

```
var Bluebird = require('bluebird');
var client = new elasticsearch.Client({
  defer: function () {
    // for older Bluebird
    // return Bluebird.defer();

    var resolve, reject;
    var promise = new PromiseImpl(function() {
      resolve = arguments[0];
      reject = arguments[1];
    });
    return {
      resolve: resolve,
      reject: reject,
      promise: promise
    };
  }
});
```

By default documentation stated that it uses ES6 Promise.

[Read more about configuration](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/configuration.html#config-defer)